# UserControl - declare custom enum and then use it in VM's

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have custom control:

```
<UserControl>
<Grid x:Name="Layout">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ProtocolType, TargetNullValue='https://'}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding Hostname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding PathType}" />
    <ProgressBar Grid.Column="3" IsIndeterminate="True" Width="40" Height="10"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Image Grid.Column="3" Width="16" Height="16" />
</Grid>
```

As you can see, it has progressbar and image. Progressbar indicates, when something is doing and Image indicates the result - ok/bad. What I want is, when I press button on MainView, progressbar will display and when operation will complete the result will be displayed as an image and hide progressbar.
My plan was to declare enum with 4 states - nothing, inprogress, ok, bad. But I'm not sure, when I declare the enum and use it for manipulating some controls in usercontrol, If I can use this enum in my ViewModel. If I will not violate the MVVM.

**EDIT:**
enum:

```
public enum Progress
    {
        InProgress,
        Success,
        Failed,
        Nothing
    }
```

VM:

```
private Progress _webServiceProgress;

    public Progress WebServiceProgress
    {
        get { return _webServiceProgress; }
        set { Set(ref _webServiceProgress, value); }
    }
```

This VM's property I would bind to my usercontrol property (DP) and according to enum value I would display progressbar/image.

Comment: There is nothing criminal in enums in MVVM, it is just a data type.

Comment: I would declare the enum in the view model. If you don't want to use the enum declaration from the VM in your UserControl, declare the same type in your UserControl library, and write a binding converter that converts from one enum to the other.

Comment: @Clemens When I declare enum in VM, then I will have to reference the VM in usercontrol.

Comment: @JuP What is your real question?

Comment: @Maxim What I want is to manipulate 2 controls (progressbar and image) in my customcontrol, using only one property, which value will be set from my ViewModels.

Comment: @JuP So... do it. I don't see question in your sentence. You don't know how to do that? Triggers will help you.

Comment: @JuP Read the second sentence in my previous comment.

Comment: @Maxim, no you don't understand. Obviously, only Clemens understood, what I want. I'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `ControlTemplate` with triggers that sets the `Visibility` property of the controls:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid x:Name="Layout">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ProtocolType, TargetNullValue='https://'}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding Hostname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding PathType}" />
                <ProgressBar x:Name="pb" Grid.Column="3" IsIndeterminate="True" Width="40" Height="10"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                <Image x:Name="img" Grid.Column="3" Width="16" Height="16" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WebServiceProgress}" Value="{x:Static local.Progress.InProgress}">
                    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    <Setter TargetName="pb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WebServiceProgress}" Value="{x:Static local.Progress.Success}">
                    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter TargetName="pb" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```